# EF4.1 Optional Column Mapping

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

I have looked already and cannot find this but does anyone know of an optional column mapping for EF4.1 -> EF4.3.  There is a NotMapped attribute but I want the column to be populated if data is returned and left as null if that column did not exist in the dataset.  The reason for doing this is simply so I can use the same object type for multiple SPs that that sometime may omit columns.  Of cause I can get around this problem simply by having a class for each SP but as the data is so similar it seemed messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such functionality in EF. You will need todo as you have described and create separate classes.